# typedef a type to a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, typedef

So, normally we typedef to another type or function pointer, but typedef a type to a pointer is strange to me. For example, in winnt.h we got:

```
typedef void *HANDLE;
typedef PVOID HANDLE;
```

and PVOID is:

```
typedef void *PVOID,*LPVOID;
```

According to that, in the first statement it must be *HANDLE because it's a pointer to void, while PVOID is already a pointer to void, therefore it needs not to be declare as a pointer.

However, what's the benefit of typedef a type to a pointer? Isn't it more confusing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> what's the benefit of typedef a type to a pointer? Isn't it more confusing?

Usually, modules/Libraries need to maintain some internal state for their proper functioning. This internal state needs to be read/verified on every api that is called for this module/library. So the user of the module needs to pass this information to every api they call. But the library implementor do not want that the users of the library be able to see the contents of this maintained statem, because if they are allowed to, someone might play mischief or make honest mitake of modifying the state, and the results of that might be drastic for the module. To avoid such an scenario the modules mask their state maintiaining variables as a `void*` so that now it is opaque(it's contents are not visible) to users of the module. For benifit of letting the users not being confused about using `void *` they usually typedef the `void *`as `HANDLE`, this is for ease of usage for the clients of the module/library.

As for the mentioned code:

```
typedef void *PVOID,*LPVOID;
```

means wherever you mention `PVOID` henceforth it will be treated as a `void *` type.
So in,

```
typedef PVOID HANDLE;
```

is equivalent to:

```
typedef void *HANDLE;
```

Because `PVOID` is nothing but `void *`.

Comment: I can't see the advantage of this over forward declaring an opaque struct like this `class HANDLE;`. That would prevent accidental missuse a little better. Or am I missing something?

Comment: And what with C API for example? ;)

Comment: So, typedef void* HANDLE is the same as typedef void *HANDLE ? Well I know about this but it's strange to me on this one.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson: The Answer says why it is done, it does not say it is the way it should be done.This is the traditional C way of doing it.And legacy codes still sometimes use it the same way.I would agree forward declaring a class is an better way but that is not always what legacy procedural c++ middleware/applications do.Yes Procedural C++ middlewares exist and it is an grim but reality.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson: A `HANDLE` can point to quite a lot of different structures. It's used for almost everything in the WIN32 (and WIN16 it comes from) API.

Comment: @Amumu: `typedef void* HANDLE` is same as `typedef void *HANDLE` the dereference `*` applies to the `void` not to the preeceding `HANDLE`.Strange but True.

Comment: @Als I was asking as that has been the way I've provided C interfaces to C++ code in the past (pointers to opaque classes, rather than pointers to void). I didn't think there was anything to be gained by going `void*` and losing typesafety.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg WIN32 using HANDLE for many things means you can pass the wrong object type to a function. Using differently named `void*` typedefs is not enough to stop this. e.g. "Oops you passed a file handle to your graphics rendering code .. that compiles fine as they're both void* under the covers."  Thats exactly the problem that a pointer to an opaque class is designed to prevent.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson You have to remember that the WIN32 API was developed from the WIN16 API, long before there were such things as C++ and classes, and most of the Windows internals probably was coded in assembler. That's the reason for HANDLE (and LPHANDLE, which show s the 16-bit origin) being created the way it is. Yes, it's easy to pass the wrong handles to the wrong functions, but if something like that slips by possible code inspection, it should be caught easily in testing when weird stuff starts to happen.

Answer (score 2):

And if you are curious why to use 2 typedefs for the same value, the answer is: they have different meaning and use cases. HANDLE is a handle to an object and PVOID is just pointer to any type. So it's just for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

speaking in english,

```
typedef void *PVOID
```

means use void * instead of PVOID. &

```
typedef PVOID HANDLE;
```

means use PVOID instead of HANDLE & due to our previous typedef this further means
use void * instead of HANDLE

this is for better readability of the code.